# Handle sharing an image into the application, and using its uri to make a copy to another folder

Tags: android

I'm making an application that will allow users to share an image into the application, and the app should save a copy in another folder for later retrieval.

*But the problem* is that it tells me that the source file doesn't exist, what did I do wrong?
*Also,* is That even a good approach? It will save a copy of the images in folders and retrieve this data in a recycler view; Is there a reason to preferer using a database?

**Here is the code for receiving a shared image:**

```
String action = getIntent().getAction(); //Action: receive a shared file.

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {
            mImageUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);


            try {
                copyFileForBiggerFiles(new File(mImageUri.getPath()), getFilesDir());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**Here is the code for copying that photo in the internal :**

```
private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {

         if (!sourceFile.exists()) { //problem accrues here
             return;
         }

         FileChannel source;
         FileChannel destination;
         source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
         destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
         if (destination != null && source != null) {
             destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
         }
         if (source != null) {
             source.close();
         }
         if (destination != null) {
             destination.close();
         }

     }
```

**Manifest:**

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
        
         ...
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    
                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Comment: from the code not found the root cause, please attached more information

Comment: Image is shared correctly and I get the uri of it, but when It reaches the `copyFile()` method `sourceFile.exists()` it returns `false` I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that a uri is not necessarily a file uri (`file://`), so using `mImageUri.getPath()` does not work when for example a content uri (`content://`) is passed from the sharing application. When you're dealing with a passed uri it's best to open your input stream using [`ContentResolver.openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) since it handles both content and file uri scheme types internally:

```
private void copyFile(Context context, Uri sourceUri, File destFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(sourceUri);
    try {
        if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
            destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        try {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

And call it in you activity:

```
copyFile(this, mImageUri.getPath(), new File(context.getFilesDir(), "fileName"));
```

Comment: You are not checking if mkdirs() fails. It could and then you are not aware. Also you are not checking return value of createFile().

Comment: Further you can remove the call to createFile. It is not needed as new FileOutputStream will create the file.

Comment: I used your code and with @blackapps suggestion, I surrounded mkdirs() with an if statement and it actually failed I don't know why; And copyFile() throw an exception that I didn't see in LogCat but knew about it using a Toast. What should I do, I can't seem to find the cause of the problem?

Comment: I think you will already have an exception when you try to open an inputstream. As uri.getPath() is still used by you.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply, I didn't get the notification! Can you explain this more.. @blackapps